# "Тут" и "здесь"

Tags: грамотная-речь

В одном моем вопросе меня поправили, сказав, что слово "тут" - разговорное, а литератураное, как я понимаю, "здесь". Честно говоря, не знала об этом. А чем "тут" хуже, чем "здесь"?
*Дополнено*: то есть, если "тут" - слово разговорное, может ли оно употребляться в художественном тексте от автора?

Comment: даже Лермонтов в своих стихах употреблял слово ТУТ... -"Чуть утро осветило пушки... французы тут как тут" (Лермонтов).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это я Вас поправила, наверное, мне и отвечать. Во-первых, давайте уточним некоторые понятия. Все стили русского ЛИТЕРАТУРНОГО языка делятся на книжные стили и разговорный. Т. е., говоря, что слово "тут" — разговорное, я ни в коей мере не имела в виду, что оно нелитературное.
Стили отличаются друг друга тем, что они используются в разных речевых ситуациях, с разными целями. Слово "здесь" — нейтральное, общеупотребительное (во всех стилях). Слово "тут" — разговорное. Оно не хуже и не лучше. Просто это слова разных стилей.
Чем спортивный стиль одежды хуже делового? Ничем. Но  уважающий себя человек в шортах на работу в официальное учреждение (если только он не спортсмен) не пойдет. Не потому что так хуже. Просто так не принято. Так и в речи.

Comment: Да, еще. Форма книжных стилей преимущественно письменная, разговорного - устная. Поэтому то, что не заметил бы в устной речи, в письменной бросается в глаза. Как слово "тут" в формулировке Вашего вопроса.

Comment: В художественном тексте могут употребляться слова всех стилей и даже просторечные, сниженные, если это отвечает целям  автора. НАпример. автор описывает молодежную вечеринку. Понятно, что герои не будут разговаривать официальным, строго нормированным языком.

Comment: Ну, здесь у нас тоже что-то вроде вечеринки! Все свои ;-))  

Я, например, люблю использовать разговорный стиль в названии своих статей (научно-популярных, по математике). Вроде печатают!

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1327135-zdes-ili-tut-kakaja-raznica.html#answer3843019) я увидел ответ, который мне кажется куда более правильным, чем деление на просторечное и литературное:

> Для меня всегда было "тут" - более конкретизированное место, а "здесь" - область, в котором находится "тут".
>
> Исхожу, наверно от подходящих "антонимов":
>
> тут - там
>
> здесь - не здесь (т.е. точно не тут, но и не факт, что там)
>
> Подтверждает такой подход фразеологизм:
>
> > Здесь Вам не тут!